# Extra insulation for panes of aging windows

Tags: windows, insulation

The original windows on my 30-year-old house are insulated pretty well around the frames, but the panes themselves transmit a lot of cold air, especially when things drop down into the single digits, as they are already this winter.  I'd like to replace most of them this Summer, but until then...

I know there are plastic wraps and such that can be applied around the frame to create an additional air pocket between the pane and the room, but do they actually work?

Are there any other techniques that I should try to keep my window panes from seeping in so much cold air?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used the plastic window stuff before (literally just finished putting up some a few minutes ago) and it works quite well. Another option to look into is storm windows, they go a long way to helping keep a house warmer.  You can purchase storm windows in standard sizes at the usual hardware stores, or order custom fit ones if they don't have the ones you need.

There are also weatherstripping products you can get for your windows.  [Wired](http://howto.wired.com/wiki/Weatherproof_Your_Windows) currently has a decent overview of what your options are.

Comment: I'll probably just replace the windows before I started to worry about storm windows.  They're casement (crank out) windows, so the storm windows wouldn't feel very natural.  I'll probably try the plastic sheets first on the worst offender (right above our favorite couch.)  If that makes it feel warmer, I'll think about covering the rest of them.