# Window insulation in a rented apartment

Tags: windows, draft

My apartment is extremely drafty during the winter months, with a window in my bedroom, as well as in my bathroom, my room suffers as soon as the temperature drops. I gave a call to my landlord and they claimed to have come out and fix it, but I felt no difference.

What would a simple DIY solution be that won't cost my roommates and I an arm and a leg, and will seal up our windows from some of the draft?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just cover the window with a heat shrinkable window insulation kit such as this one below available at any home store. It will come with the needed tape to affix it to the window frame (from the inside of the apartment) and then all you need is a hair dryer to tighten it up to a nice clean and clear view. Once summer comes again, it will easily remove without any paint damage as the adhesive is similar to a PostIt notepad type system.

[image]

Comment: I used this in the past, but the double sided tape you put on the frames did not come of without damaging the paint, so the landlord may not like it.  (They may have got better, since I used one about 10 years ag0)

Comment: I use blue painters tape around the window and then put the double-sided tape over that. Worked fine but you end up with blue tape around your window which is a little strange. I'm sure you could use the same type of tape but a different color...

Answer (score 2):

Look at [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/extra-insulation-for-panes-of-aging-windows/3412#3412) which covers similar grounds. But the short answer is the sealing plastic film that you can get at pretty much any hardware store will do the trick. It's cheap, effective, and removes easily when you're done with it.