# Single pane windows with outside screens

Tags: windows

My house use to have old windows with storms I had to install outside each winter.  Through a grant, I had new windows installed.  They are double hung, single pane, with screens to the outside.  Do I leave the screens on during the winter?  How do I keep the cold out with single panes?

Comment: I see that you're also in Minnesota. I have to ask... are you 100% sure that they're single-pane? I don't know the last time I saw single-pane windows around here, where it regularly reaches -30F in the winter, especially in new windows.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that wasn't much of an upgrade. I'm afraid you're stuck with having to use that [plastic stuff](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/extra-insulation-for-panes-of-aging-windows?rq=1) or installing extra storm windows.

Answer (score 1):

Install insulating shutters.

From [energy.gov](http://energy.gov/energysaver/energy-efficient-window-treatments):

> Solid shutters will decrease both heat loss and summer heat gain. Insulating shutters consist of wood panels, a vapor barrier, and sometimes a decorative covering. If you fit them tightly against a window frame, they'll provide an insulating air space between the shutter and the window.

Too bad... I would have thought any grant would specify modern efficient windows.